# Unix - How to find what place a word comes in a sentence

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Basically, I'm writing a shell script in Unix and I need to retrieve a value that says what place a word occurs in a sentence/string and then store that value in a variable.

For example, the word "blue" is the third word in the following sentence "the fast blue car".  Therefore, I'd like the value for this word to be 3 and store it in a variable called $blue.  I.e. echo $blue would print out the number 3.

All the examples I've found so far print out the position of a word in terms of characters not words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
tokens=$(echo $text | sed 's/[.\\\/;,?!:]//g') # Add any missing punctuation marks here
$pos = 0
for token in $tokens
do
    pos=$(($pos + 1))
    if [[ "$token" == "fox" ]]
    then
        echo $pos
    fi
done
```

This'll print the position of the word "fox" (4 in this case) out to the command line. Multiple occurrences of the word will yield multiple outputs.

Comment: This does exactly what I need... thanks!  My Unix experience is really basic... would you be able to give a quick description of what the tokens line is doing please?

Comment: @data101: It strips out punctuation characters. The way bash handles strings, they would get included in each item being processed. For instance, `[[ "$token" == "fox" ]]` would match `fox` but not `'fox'`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another in awk. Borrowing @SebastianLenartowicz's `$text`:

```
$ text="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"  # in lower and no punctuations

$ echo $text | awk -v RS="[ \n]" -v s=fox '$0==s{print NR}'
4
```

Explained:

- `-v RS="[ \n]"` *R*ecord *S*eparator to space or newline
- `-v s=fox`search word goes to script in variable `s`
- `$0==s{print NR}` if the record (`$0`) equals `s` print the row or *record*  number `NR`

Comment: this is a really nice answer!  Does what I need in a single line!