# How do I find which position a word is in a string?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gnu

For instance, if I have the variable

```
var="dog cat owl fish"
```

and I want to input "cat" (the second word in a string of words separated by spaces) and get "2" returned , how would I do this in a shell script without bash?

Comment: What do you mean by "without bash"? What shell are you using?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382712/bash-how-to-tokenize-a-string-variable

Comment: I'm using sh, I tried looking at awk options but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "without bash"?

The following works in bash, dash, and ksh:

```
#!/bin/____  <- insert your shell here

input=$1
var="dog cat owl fish"

i=1
set -f
for word in $var ; do
    if [ "$word" = "$input" ] ; then
        echo $i
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

`set -f` prevents `*` in `$var` from pathname expansion. In zsh, you need `set -o SH_WORD_SPLIT 1` to split `$var` in the for loop.

Comment: I would suggest disabling filename expansion first, in case you get something like  `var="*"`

Comment: @glennjackman: I have no idea how portable that is, though.

Comment: `set -f` is specified in POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set

Comment: @glennjackman: It seems it's not needed in zsh. Do you have any idea how to turn it **on** in zsh?

Comment: no, not a zsh user. I use fish as my interactive shell

Answer (score 1):

With some core utilities:

```
echo "$var" | tr " " "\n" | grep -n "$input" | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Match complete words with `grep -n "^${input}$"`

Answer (score 0):

This information came from a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011858/unix-how-to-find-what-place-a-word-comes-in-a-sentence). I just altered it to hopefully fit your problem.

```
var="dog cat owl fish"
target=$1
tokens=$(echo $var | sed 's/[.\\\/;,?!:]//g') # Add any missing punctuation marks here
pos=0
for token in $tokens
do
    pos=$(($pos + 1))
    if [[ "$token" = "$target" ]] #you could use just $1 if you wanted to instead declaring the target variable.
    then
        echo $pos
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's good, thank you

Comment: No problem!  @SarahMyers

Comment: I fixed your variable assignment errors.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the edit! I'm sorry I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned awk in the comments:

```
$ echo $var | awk -v s=cat '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="cat")print i}'
2
```

Explained:

```
echo $var |            # echo $var to awk
awk -v s=cat '{        # parameterized search word
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) # iterate every word
        if($i==s)      # if current word is the searched one
            print i    # print its position
}'
```

If it's possible to have newlines in the var (sh mentioned):

```
$ var="dog cat\nowl fish"                
$ echo $var
dog cat
owl fish
$ echo $var | awk -v RS="^$" -v s=owl '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==s)print i}'
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
animals="dog cat owl fish"
tokens=( $animals )
echo ${tokens[1]}
```